# Secondary powers required to make an "air scooter" work for a person with wind powers?

Tags: physics, super-powers

When demons took over the modern world, they killed most of humanity, and for those that survived, at least in some cases, they started developing powers. For example, one of these powers is the ability to control the wind, able to make blasts of wind, though not enough to fly, and to compress and mold it into any shape they want, like making a little dancer out of air that can dance in the palm of their hand.

I thought about having this character be able to use their power to make an "air scooter," as in a ball of wind they can ride to travel at high speeds, but I'm fairly certain it would be more complicated than "make ball out of wind, hop on, and then ride the wind ball." What would be the required secondary powers to make this power function in a way that could make an "air scooter" a viable means of transportation? Also, for visual reference:

[image: Air Scooter]

Answer (score 1):

**Use wind ball to produce lift.**

I am thinking your character could wear a long dress-like garment attached at the ankles.  The wind ball would go under the dress and produce higher pressure and thus lift.  You would want a tight belt to keep the wind ball from just exiting at the collar, and a big belt buckle because that looks sharp.

The dress would not blow up and inside out because of the ankle attachments. But you could use the ankle attachments to steer and it would look like you were dancing.

I think a pair of fans, one in each hand would also help with steering.

Illustrations very welcome.